# jQuery Mobile listview widget on click event not firing for Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to bind to the click event of listview item which works fine in the browser but when I run it on Android Emulator (webview) as an application with cordova, I get nothing and no console output either. I have replicated the problem with JSBin (link below) it works fine in the browser but not in android studios emulator which is basically just a webview.

HTML

```
<ul id="maclist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li>
       <a id="23234234">
       <img src="../_assets/img/album-bb.jpg">
       <h2>Broken Bells</h2>
       <p>Broken Bells</p>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a id="97893636">
       <img src="../_assets/img/album-hc.jpg">
       <h2>Warning</h2>
       <p>Hot Chip</p>
       </a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a id="14235454">
       <img src="../_assets/img/album-p.jpg">
       <h2>Wolfgang Amadeus Phoenix</h2>
       <p>Phoenix</p>
       </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('#maclist').on('click', 'li a', function(event) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(id);

    // Fetch data from API using id
});
```

I just need to grab the id of the current element so I can do a request to fetch data from my API. I have other on click events which work fine in the application, the data in my listview is dynamically generated if that matters this is just an example using JSBin. So why is my on click event unresponsive in webview on mobile devices but works on desktop browsers?

https://jsbin.com/xoyuveloje/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#maclist a', function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

---

> The jQuery Mobile "vclick" event handler simulates the "onclick" event
>   handler on mobile devices.

**vclick** reference: https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

Regarding the dynamically generated list items, please see [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/) the difference between Direct and delegated event handlers:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist at the time your code makes the call to .on()
>
> Delegated event handlers have the advantage that they can process
>   events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a
>   later time.

Comment: this also does not work in the emulator but does work correctly in my browser

Comment: Where did You placed the event handler? JQM must be loaded and DOM must be loaded.

Comment: I know it's weird because I have other on click functions working on dynamic content I have it inside doc ready could it be this widget?

Comment: sorry you were right all along and I had a hashtag in my html `id="#maclist"` thanks mate